# FLASH AS2 dynamically added button

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

```
_root.attachMovie("zoom_btn", "zoom_btn", _root.getNextHighestDepth());

zoom_btn.onRelease = function() {
    _root.attachMovie("blank_btn", "blank_btn", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
    blank_btn._x=200;
}

//zoom_btn.onRelease();

blank_btn.onRelease = function() {
    trace ("click");
}
```

After clicking on "zoom_btn", "blank_btn" adding on stage from library (export for AS is ON).

When i click on "blank_btn", nothing happens. Trace not working.

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: If i uncomment line 8, all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because when you add the `onRelease` handler on blank_btn, `blank_btn` is `undefined`. 
Try to add a `trace(blank_btn)` just before you define your `onRelease` function, it will output `undefined`.

When you uncomment `zoom_btn.onRelease();`, its working because it creates `bank_btn` before adding the `onRelease` handler.

If you want to do that, you need to do something like :

```
zoom_btn = _root.attachMovie("zoom_btn", "zoom_btn", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
zoom_btn.onRelease = createBlankButton

function createBlankButton() {
    blank_btn = _root.attachMovie("blank_btn", "blank_btn", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
    blank_btn._x=200;
    blank_btn.onRelease = function() {
        trace ("click");
    }
}
```